# GPU device emulator

Tags: cuda

I am new to learning CUDA and I was looking around for a good emulator to run my CUDA programs on, since my laptop does not come with a Graphics card.

I have heard of mcuda and gpuocelot but they seem to have terrible and confusing documentation. I have been trying to get them installed for a few hours now but with very little progress.

Does any one know of a decent GPU emulator with good documentation. I am using Ubuntu 10.10
operating system

Thank you,

Gaurish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**nvcc** has an option to turn on the emulation mode and will run the entire application on your CPU. You don't need to have a CUDA enabled GPU for this, of course.

```
nvcc -deviceemu my_first_app.cu
```

Comment: Is that still the case? I thought it had been removed since 3.1? Might be mistaken though.

Comment: See http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/cudatoolkit_release_notes_linux.txt under "new toolkit features".

Comment: hmm...well I guess the -deviceemu option will do for now, since I am a CUDA newbie. I have got this option to work. Thank you karlphillip!. However for this I need to use CUDA 2.3. But since this is an outdated version of CUDA I might need to migrate to GPUocelot/MCUDA eventually anyway.

Comment: @karlphillip: The old API based emulation mode was deprecated and removed from CUDA during the 3.x release cycle. What you are suggesting won't work on any CUDA version newer than 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I tried for GPUocelot on ubuntu 12.04.
its time consuming job we have to download some folders from "http://gpuocelot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ "I hope it will work after downloading these folders using svn.
here is link where you can find all steps to install gpuocelot
http://barefeg.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/how-to-install-gpuocelot-in-ubuntu-12-04